# turn array with object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

Let's say I have this:

```
[ { 'one': '8b45544b-6d35c53c3d423' },
  { 'two': '5a509481-a43k4d40r4c44' } ]
```

How can I turn it into this:

```
[ 'one', 'two' ]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Some actual research would yield a million answers

Comment: I tried to use `.filter` but it's didn't work out for this case I think.

Comment: Could you post your code sample? Thanks :D

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately this is too broad for here. If you can show us the code that you tried we can help, but we can't write all the code for you. Sow us what you've tried and what issues you're running into! Here is a helpful guide for [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why would you try to use `.filter`? That's for returning the elements of an array that matches a condition. It has nothing to do with extracting parts of objects.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[ { 'one': '8b45544b-6d35c53c3d423' },
  { 'two': '5a509481-a43k4d40r4c44' } ].map(o => Object.keys(o)[0])
```

Comment: to who down vote, copy it to console, it works.